# Jmeter Beanshell post processor not writting anything to csv file

Tags: jmeter

I have simple code like this-

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;

import java.io.FileWriter;
num1 = vars.get("num");

log.info("num1");


 FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\abc\\r.csv", true);
 BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
 out.write(vars.get("num"));
 out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
 out.close();
 fstream.close();
```

however it is not working and nothing gets to the csv file.  I can see the number printed in the log file with log statement. Also there are no errors.

Comment: your path `C:\abc\\r.csv` does not escape one of the backslashes, should be `C:\\abc\\r.csv`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make sure that `num1` variable is not null, in order to check it amend the line which prints it out as:

   ```
   log.info(num1);
   ```

   You need to remove quotation marks around `num1` to see the actual value
2. You need to escape "abc" folder name with double backslash:

   ```
   FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\abc\\r.csv", true);
   ```
3. Maybe it would be easier to use [FileUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#writeStringToFile(java.io.File,%20java.lang.String,%20java.nio.charset.Charset,%20boolean)) class like:

   ```
   import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("C:\\abc\\r.csv), vars.get("num"), true);
   FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File("C:\\abc\\r.csv"), System.getProperty("line.separator"), true);
   ```
4. You can print a lot of Beanshell debugging into STDOUT by adding `debug();` directive at the very beginning of your Beanshell script. Also consider using [Debug Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Debug_Sampler) and [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener combination to check JMeter Variables and Properties values. See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException; //import IOException, you'll need it later
import java.io.File; // this too :)

int num1 = vars.get("num"); // you need to declare variable type, int in your case, othrewise it's an error
log.info(String.valueOf(num1)); //use String.valueOf() to convert int to String before logging

try {
    // you need to escape '\', or better use linux-style paths
    File myCsv = new File("C:/abc/r.csv");

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(myCsv, true);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(num1);
    out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    out.close();
    fstream.close();
} catch (IOException exc) {
    // in case any error occurs, catch it and log
    log.error("Failed to write to file!\r\n" + exc.getMessage());
}
```

Not sure, if you need to add all those imports, theoretically jmeter should get them automatically, but I don't have any meanings to check right now.
**Update:**
Make sure the directory where your r.csv is exists and you have permissions to write there.